# Chanukas Habayis

Tags: halacha, transactions, real-estate

In Chutz Laaretz do you make a Chanukas Habayis? Do the Halachic requirements and process differ from in Israel?

Answer (score 5):

אוצר דינים ומנהגים pages [137](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37057&st=&pgnum=148)-[138](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37057&st=&pgnum=149) discusses this.

It does not diffrentiate between Chutz LAretz and Eretz Yisroel.

Comment: You could improve this answer by citing your source by title and page, or whatever, rather than just linking.