# Is the Chanukat Habayit Observed Differently for Ashkenazim vs Sephardim?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, home-house, parties-celebrations

When moving into a new home, is there a difference of how to celebrate the Chanukat Habayit?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18001/501 What are the halachot of Chanukat Habayit?

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of that, @DannySchoemann? It seems like one to me.

Comment: It does not answer the question about the "different" customs b/w Ashkenazim and Sephardim.

Comment: @MikeS, if answers are the only issue, then it is indeed a duplicate. I'm closing it, and I recommend http://mi.yodeya.com/help/no-one-answers